# Joda Time: Invalid format. Data is malformed

Tags: java, jodatime

Trying to process this string with date and time:

```
2015-10-23T00:00:00+03:00
```

By using this code:

```
String transactionDateValue = getNodeValue(nodeList, i, "transactionDate");
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss ZZZ");
DateTime jodaTime = dateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(transactionDateValue);
DateTimeFormatter resultFormat = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

This is the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "2015-10-23T00:00:00+03:00" is malformed at "T00:00:00+03:00"

    at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(DateTimeFormatter.java:945)
    at repgen.service.PrepareExcelService.fillContent(PrepareExcelService.java:169)
    at repgen.service.PrepareExcelService.prepareDocument(PrepareExcelService.java:44)
    at repgen.service.PrepareExcelServiceTest.testPrepareExcelService(PrepareExcelServiceTest.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.mockito.internal.junit.JUnitRule$1.evaluate(JUnitRule.java:16)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:37)
    at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:62)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:117)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:262)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

I suspect my error is near the ZZZ parameter, but cannot solve it. I also tried the parameters ZZZZ, ZZ, but that didn't fix it.

Comment: It's because the string you are trying to parse contains a `T` which is not in the format string. By the way, this is standard ISO-8601 format which Joda Time already supports, you don't need to use a custom format string. Just do `DateTime jodaTime = DateTime.parse(transactionDateValue);`

Comment: Thanks! This worked like a charm!

Comment: Try this code :                                                                                                   DateTime jodaTime = DateTime.parse("2015-10-23T00:00:00+03:00");
  DateTimeFormatter resultFormat = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
  System.out.println(resultFormat.print(jodaTime));

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This happens because the string you are trying to parse contains a `T`, which is not in the format string.

You are trying to parse a string which is in the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. You do not need a custom date format string for this, because Joda Time already supports this format by default. Just do:

```
DateTime jodaTime = DateTime.parse(transactionDateValue);
```

Answer (score 11):

Your Format must be:

```
DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
```

It must be exactly like the date string, with the fixed values escaped by single quotes and without additional blanks.
Also you have to use `HH`for 24 hours Format. hh is 12 hours Format and it starts at 1 and Ends on 12

Comment: edited above comment while you edited yours. Works now as expected. Thanks!

Comment: this worked for me thanks! however in my case I had to add my Z between '' like 'Z'